# Developing both Applied and Theoretical Interests

Tags: career-path, early-career

I've seen profiles of researchers who, over time, come to work in both theoretical and applied areas, although I suspect (having seen profiles of other researchers who recently finished their PhD) that these researchers had one forte to begin with.

As an undergraduate hoping to become a researcher, I'd like to develop both interests one day.

Is that possible in both directions? Can I go to school to become a theoretician and later develop applied interests; or go to school to become an applied researcher but later learn and pursue more theoretical interests?

As an example, I'd like to one day both deeply understand statistical theory and yet have the skillset to work with data. Is it better to start off in one area?

Comment: Working with data is not a problem, anybody can learn Mathematica/Matlab/Java/C/C++... in 2 3 months, but not anyone would be interested enough to learn theoretical physics(general relativity and quantum physics takes years..)

Comment: _Working with data is not a problem_ -- [citation needed]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes you can. Now, how/why do researchers change directions? Many reasons;

1. Chasing different funding/proposals venues.
2. Being part of a school or department where interaction of professors and available lab equipment can lead (with time) to you redirecting your research.
3. When advising students for MS/PhD or being a part of search/research committees, one tend to think outside the box (outside of his research area) and incorporate different methods/ideas
4. You learn more new stuff with time! Remember that a PhD in subject X does not mean that you get to work in X for the rest of your life. It simply means that you know X (in details) much more than other people (or professors).

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you can

There are actually two parts to your question:

### Why so?

As times change, seasons change, people's interest also change. The change between application and theoretical domains can be due to one or more of many factors as pointed out by @TheFireGuy.

An extra point I'd like to add would be the flair of ideas that may pop up from time to time causing the shift between the fields.

### Why not?

There may be some researchers who seem to be fairly comfortable in their current field and might be resistant towards switching between theoretical and applied research. Such people may have explored several fields before arriving at this one or just selected it randomly due to some influencing factor.